Dynamical System Local Asymptotic Stability with Nontrivial Kernel
I’m trying to investigate the local asymptotic stability of critical points in a certain autonomous system. Specifically, we’re looking at trajectories satisfying $\dot{x} = f(x)$ for a non-linear $f$ on a Banach space $V$. The issue is that the critical points $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$ are not necessarily isolated.
Given a critical point $x_0$, my understanding is that we can investigate the asymptotic stability near $x_0$ through the spectrum of the linear operator $D_{x_0} f$. For my function, I have proven that this operator has a real non-positive spectrum. If the spectrum were negative, I would know that we have local asymptotic stability. But in general, $0$ will be in the spectrum for me. Are there any results that are useful in this case? Thanks!

"Center manifold theory" may be a good starting point for searching literature
